# Excel - Array formula into dropdown

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be greatly appreciative.

I am trying to work an array formula and a data validation list (dropdown) together, so that instead of the array formula dumping the result to the sheet, it populates a dropdown with the values it finds.

Scenario:
I have a set of data like the screenshot below, what I need is to be able to specify a socket number and then be able to choose the available duct and exit values from a dropdown list.
I have tried using VLOOKUP and INDEX MATCH together with a data validation list however neither of those methods allow for multiple results.

Data:

[image: Data]

Thank you for reading.

Comment: It would be much easier if you add some examples, directions you've tested, etc.

Comment: I added my scenario and some dummy data, I hope this helps.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43047363/2193968

Comment: I have, however with the method I'm using (array formulas, because I don't know any other way to display multiple results of a formula) this isn't possible