# Data validationlist with formula

Tags: excel

Is there a way to have a list like here below but with code (instead of the hardcoded I did for this example):
[image]

Cell G5 has now: `=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)`

Data validation list source should be something like:
`=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)` and `=CONCATENATE(A1,B1," - ",D$1$)`

This previous question is different than mine (because it's only one formula):
[How to put formula in Data Validation List Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459322/how-to-put-formula-in-data-validation-list-excel)

Comment: If you could, you'd end up with the formulas showing in the dropdown, not the result of the formulas. You'll have to put those formulas in a range somewhere.

Comment: Hello @Rory, thanks for your comment, I will use this as solution to my problem, it's the less complex way.

Answer (score 2):

As @rory already said: you will have to put the list somewhere on the sheet and refer the data validation list to that list:

You can use this formula to retrieve the list, put it e.g. in cell `X1`:

```vb
=LET(base,A1:B2,ext,$D$1,
simple,BYROW(base,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,r))),
SORT(VSTACK(simple,simple & " - " & ext)))
```

You then refer to that list in the data validation by using `X1#`.

Comment: Hello @Ike , thanks for your answer. But I will be using the solution proposed by Rory, it's the less complex in my case. Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: Rory suggested the same ... I provided the formula to get the values for the list